# Writing text to .txt file using PHP

Tags: php, html, post

So I have page.txt which looks like this:

```
<textarea name="msg" rows="1"></textarea>
<form id="post" name="post" action="storeText.php" method="post">
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Set news now"/>
</form>
```

I also have storeText.php which looks like this:

```
<?php       
$filename = 'posts.txt';
$msg = (isset($_POST['msg']) ? $_POST['msg'] : null);

    // Let's make sure the file exists and is writable first.
    if (is_writable($filename)) {

    // In our example we're opening $filename in append mode.
    // The file pointer is at the bottom of the file hence
    // that's where $somecontent will go when we fwrite() it.
    if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'a')) {
        echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
        exit;
    }

    // Write $somecontent to our opened file.
    if (fwrite($handle, $msg) === FALSE) {
        echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
        exit;
    }

    echo "Success, wrote ($msg) to file ($filename)";

    fclose($handle);

    } else {
    echo "The file $filename is not writable";
    }
?>
```

Now it should write the text onto posts.txt but it always says "Success, wrote () to file...". Notice the empty parenthesis which should have my input.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the full HTML of the form? Possibly a problem there

Comment: seeing your `<textarea>` element outside the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<textarea name="msg" rows="1"></textarea>
<form id="post" name="post" action="storeText.php" method="post">
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Set news now"/>
</form>
```

If the textarea is outside of the form block it won't be sent. So your html should look like:

```
<form id="post" name="post" action="storeText.php" method="post">
    <textarea name="msg" rows="1"></textarea>
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Set news now"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. How would I also change the PHP so it replaces the txt file's text with the new text inputted? Currently it adds the inputted text onto whatever is already there.

Comment: looking at [fopen](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) you should change `a` to `w`

Comment: @stevetheipad see `fopen` mode type [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

Answer (score 0):

Your `<textarea>` element is outside of your `<form>` tags.

`<textarea>`should either go inside the form tags or you need to specify a `form` attribute to link the input to a form e.g. `<textarea form="myForm">` (the latter may not work in older browsers, though, best to put it inside the `<form>` tag if you can).

That's why your `$_POST['msg']` is null